# Service to monitor current foreground app

Tags: android

I have searched everywhere and most of the posts are very old.

I am looking to make a service that will be monitoring just what is the current foreground App (package name), so in case where it requires the use of the microphone, i can release the microphone in my app so they can use it.

I dont have a recording app, or spy app, i am using the app to recognize audio, and it has the possibility to stay in the background to recognize audio.

Does anyone know any functionality that i can use to achieve this? Activity Manager maybe or something?

Thanks.

Comment: "so in case where it requires the use of the microphone, i can release the microphone in my app so they can use it" -- why not use the audio focus APIs? After all, you have no idea whether the foreground app needs the microphone, based solely on the package name. "Does anyone know any functionality that i can use to achieve this?" -- hopefully there is none, as Google has been taking steps to lock this information down, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Can you provide any more info on the audio focus API?

Comment: [This page](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) covers them with an emphasis on output. I assume/hope that there is an input equivalent, though I have not used it.

Comment: doesnt look like there is one

Comment: I would still focus on that sort of direction: see what audio focus equivalent exists for the microphone.

Comment: Yes i know and i would prefer to go that way, but unfortunately i havent found anything equivalent or similar. I am trying to achieve fairness for the mic, since right now i have found solution on how to release the microphone when the user is in the app and some other app requests the microphone, like Skype,Viber, WhatsApp call, and i can regain the microphone after they are finished, the only problem is when the app is in the background already, and some other app needs the microphone.

Comment: I put a small bounty on your earlier question, to see if we can get any more possible answers there.

Comment: thank you for the help CommonsWare